# Issue with minikube / kvm2

Tags: minikube

I have this issue when running "minikube start --vm-driver kvm2":

> E0109 11:23:34.536027   22169 start.go:187] Error starting host: Error
>   starting stopped host: Error creating VM: virError(Code=1, Domain=10,
>   Message='internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor:
>   2019-01-09 16:23:34.183+0000: Domain id=11 is tainted: host-cpu
>   2019-01-09T16:23:34.284194Z qemu-kvm: unrecognized feature kvm').

Result of lsmod kvm:

> [root@smu-ws ~]# lsmod | grep kvm kvm_intel             225280  0 kvm 
>   647168  1 kvm_intel irqbypass              16384  1 kvm

Result of virt-host-validate, everything PASS except:

> QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support
>   : WARN (No ACPI DMAR table found, IOMMU either disabled in BIOS or not
>   supported by this hardware platform)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this on RHEL by

```
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/minikube
$ sudo rm -rf .minikube/ (from home directory)
$ curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/v0.34.1/minikube-linux-amd64 && chmod +x minikube && sudo cp minikube /usr/local/bin/ && rm minikube
$ minikube start --vm-driver kvm2
  minikube v0.34.1 on linux (amd64)
  Creating kvm2 VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Downloading Minikube ISO ...
 184.30 MB / 184.30 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
  "minikube" IP address is 192.168.39.29
  Configuring Docker as the container runtime ...
✨  Preparing Kubernetes environment ...
  Downloading kubeadm v1.13.3
  Downloading kubelet v1.13.3
  Pulling images required by Kubernetes v1.13.3 ...
  Launching Kubernetes v1.13.3 using kubeadm ...
  Configuring cluster permissions ...
  Verifying component health .....
  kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
  Done! Thank you for using minikube!
```